# List All Combinations (Python)

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics, python-itertools

I am trying to output all the combinations of a list with certain constraints:

I need to print all the combinations of length x with domain 1 to y.

For instance, let x=3, and domain y=4. I need to generate all possible combinations of 1 to 4 with 3 members, no repetitions:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
```

I know that this should be y choose x but its hard to figure out how to loop to find all the combinations.

Using itertools I know how to generate all combinations of length x of a given list:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3],2))
```

but I am lost as to how I should generate all combinations with a certain domain.

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations(range(1, y+1), x))`?

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. How would I convert the () to []?

Comment: how about `map(list, list_of_combinations)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a list from 1 to `y`, use `range(1, y+1)`.  With this knowledge, it should be pretty straightforward to take your current `itertools` knowledge and apply it to the problem:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.combinations(range(1, y+1), x))
```

To get each result as a list instead of a tuple, you can use a list comprehension:

```
print [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(range(1, y+1), x)]
```

Or an alternative using `map()`:

```
print map(list, itertools.combinations(range(1, y+1), x))
```